# On the Display of `Sq.' and `Sqq.' with the Makeidx Package

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
suffix_2p "~sq."
suffix_3p "~sqq."
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Text.\index{A word}
\clearpage
Text.\index{A word}

Text2.\index{Another word}
\clearpage
Text2.\index{Another word}
\clearpage
Text2.\index{Another word}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index:

[image]

Question: How may I modify the code in order to have a comma follow each page number in the index? i.e., `1, sq.' and` 2, sqq.'

Comment: `suffix_2p ",~sq."` and same for `_3p` or do you mean something else?

Comment: @David Carlisle I'm not sure what you mean. If the index entry spans two pages, I would like sq. to appear; and over three pages, sqq. to appear---which the output already produces.  Is there something I am not seeing? Thank you.

Comment: I just added a comma before your `~` in the makindex style so that you get a comma before the space in the output, but that seemed too simple, so I wasn't sure if I understood the question.

Comment: @David Carlisle Many thanks! That seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the commas to your makeindex style so

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
suffix_2p ",~sq."
suffix_3p ",~sqq."
\end{filecontents}
```